# Bootstrap PHP Form Does Not Send Aything

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to finish a project to help out a friend with his website and I can't get the contact form to work. When I hit send: it seems like it has sent but then nothing ends up in the inbox of the email address. (I can't even get Stackoverflow to work... keep getting a "your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code")

Bellow is the website:
pservices.comuf.com

Bellow is the PHP code:

```
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'cgramsinjapan@hotmail.com'; // PUT YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE
$email_subject = "P Services Contact Form:  $name"; // EDIT THE EMAIL SUBJECT LINE HERE
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website's contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@your-domain.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Comment: Do you have Firebug? Can you examine the POST request in console and see if anything is posted?

Comment: Just FYI, bootstrap won't interfere with form submission in any way. The problem likely is in your HTML

Comment: I am viewing your contact page and its HTML source as I go. You have a syntax error in `name="email "id="email"` which should read as `name="email" id="email"` plus, you need to add `action="mail.php"` depending on what your PHP file name is called for your mail. You need to reload my answer and read it completely. Your form still reads as `<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate method="post">` with no action.

Comment: Ok, now you have 2x forms. `<form method="post" action="contact_me.php" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>` and `<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate method="post">` remove the 2nd one `<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate method="post">`.

Comment: Thanks Fred: I feel that I am much closer to getting this problem resolved... but still no success.

Comment: You're welcome Caleb. Your code should all check out. Add error reporting to the top of your PHP mail file 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Also check your Spam.

Comment: You can also change `mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;` to `if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){ echo "Mail sent successfully.";} else{ echo "Error.";}` - If it echoes a success, then `mail` has been successfully sent. If it echoes Error, then it's a server problem. Check your mail logs.

Comment: Yup: says "Mail sent successfully." but no mail: I'm going to try and figure it out tomorrow. Thanks again Fred.

Comment: You're welcome Caleb. I'm pretty sure it's a server issue or check your Spam box. If mail states it's been sent, then it has. Otherwise, you would have gotten an error. Did you add `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP mail file? That will signals errors caused by anything, including mail.

Comment: If this `$headers = "From: noreply@your-domain.com\n";` is what you're actually using, try using a real Email address. Many a times, mail clients will ignore it if the `From` isn't from an existing Email account.

Comment: I'm going to try on another server when I try again tomorrow. Have a good morning buddy.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, you too. Actually it's midnight here. I really have to hit the sack. I'll keep an eye out for your comments. Plus, use the `@` symbol followed by my name, that way I'll get a notification. *Cheers*

Comment: It was the server: I was using 000webhost.com (it's free) and apparently you get what you pay for. :)

Comment: *Ah,* I see. I know of them and use their service also, but purely for testing purposes only. I've never had problems with them before, yet am glad the root of the problem has been found. There are some pretty good low-rate hosting services out there too. *Cheers* and thanks for the update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Far as I can see after going to the contact section of the site you posted, none of your form elements contain a name attribute.

For instance:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
```

would need to be changed to

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

while adding the appropriate name attributes to the other form inputs.

You cannot rely on the `id` attribute alone.

Also this

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
```

is missing a post method and an action:

change it to

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
```

using `handler.php` as the PHP mail handler filename example.

You can also change these two lines:

```
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
```

to:

```
if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){ 
echo "Mail sent successfully.";
} 
else{ echo "Error.";
}
```

If it echoes a success, then `mail()` has been successfully sent.

If it echoes **Error**, then it's a server problem. Check your mail logs.

Comment: Hehe, on reading the title of this question my first thought was "I wonder if he's missing `name` attributes" ;)

Comment: @Phil That was the same thought I had also Phil. Luckily the OP left a URL I could look at in order to be sure.